# Row count with SpreadsheetLight

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio, spreadsheetlight

I'm looking for a function similar to DataTable.Rows.Count that can be used with an SLDocument to find out how many rows have data in them.  Is there something available in SpreadsheetLight?  Any other methods of achieving this?

-Brendan

Answer (score 10):

```
SLWorksheetStatistics stats1 = firstdoc.GetWorksheetStatistics();


for (int j = 1; j < stats1.EndRowIndex; j++)
{
    var value = firstdoc.GetCellValueAsString(0, j)  ;

}
```

Comment: It should be :

`for (int j = 1; j <= stats1.EndRowIndex; j++)`

Excel (and SpreadsheetLight) are 1-based indexing.

Answer (score 0):

```
var stats = sheet.GetWorksheetStatistics(); //sheet::SLDocument
var columnsCount = stats.NumberOfColumns;
var rowsCount = stats.NumberOfRows;
```