# How to copy one Excel file to another using spreadsheet light in VB.NET?

Tags: excel, vb.net, spreadsheetlight

I have a code wherein I am taking two files. Both are Excel files and I need to copy one file to another. The number of rows and columns in the files are dynamic.

`sFile` is the source file and `sFile1` is the destination file. I need to know the number of rows in source file to run a for loop when am copying it to destination file.

The code is below:

```
Dim shtlight As New SLDocument(sFile1) 
Dim lrow As Integer 
Dim lcol As Integer 
Dim sflie = Environment.Directory & "\Data.xls" 
lrow = 2  
Dim shtlight1 As New SLDocument(sFile1) 

For each row in sfile1 
    for column in sfile1 'code here to set value next next
```

I want help in running this for loop, don't know how to set the upper bound as no of rows and columns in file is dynamic.

Can someone help please? I am using phone so format might not be correct. :(

Comment: Have you seen [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325827/row-count-with-spreadsheetlight)

Comment: Ya the EndrowIndex is not working in vb. net

Comment: I have never worked with `SSLight`. However I am ready to experiment with you :) Does `.GetWorksheetStatistics()` work in vb.net for you?

Comment: Some thing like `Private stats = shtlight1.GetWorksheetStatistics()` and then `Private rowcount = stats.NumberOfRows`?

Comment: what is stats? It does work but I need to declare stats, what is the variabe type?

Comment: stats. number ofrows doesn't work, no such valid appender

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments above, I have never worked with `SpreadsheetLight`. I just downloaded `SpreadsheetLight` and experimented with it.

To get the last row you need to use this

```
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXML
Imports DocumentFormat.OpenXML.Spreadsheet
Imports SpreadsheetLight

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim sl As New SLDocument("C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Tester.xlsx", "Sheet1")
        MessageBox.Show (sl.GetWorksheetStatistics.EndRowIndex)
    End Sub
End Class
```

[image]

**Note**

For someone who is novice like me to SpreadsheetLight and would like to experiment.

1. Reference set to DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll (*Open XML SDK 2.0*). Can be downloaded from [Here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=5124). It didn't work with *Open XML SDK 2.5* for me and I didn't put too much into it to find out to why...
2. Reference set to SpreadsheetLight. Can be downloaded from [Here](http://spreadsheetlight.com/download/)

Above code is tested on VS 2013